# Pausing until CLLocation is not nil

Tags: ios, swift, admob, cllocationmanager

I've installed AdMob in an app and I've configured it to work properly. One issue I've encountered is my `CLLocationManager` is a little laggy at startup.

I have my `CLLocationManager` set up as a singleton class that's called on `AppDelegate.swift` in `didFinishLoadingWithOptions` with the following line:

```
LocationManager.sharedInstance.startUpdatingLocation()
```

In my app's initial viewController, I created a method to load ads that's called in `viewDidAppear`. I put it there so if the user navigates away from that tab, a new ad will be loaded when they come back to this tab.

**Two questions:**

1) Is there a better way to deal with lag in updating `CLLocationManager`?

2) Would it OK to store the `currentLocation` in `NSUserDefaults` and pull that location in if location services are enabled, but currentLocation is nil due to startup lag?

```
func loadAd() {

    // Google Banner
    print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())

    // TODO: need to update this for production
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        // Added this if statement to get around laggyness issue.
        if LocationManager.sharedInstance.currentLocation != nil {
            currentLocation = LocationManager.sharedInstance.currentLocation
            adRequest.setLocationWithLatitude(CGFloat((currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!),
                longitude: CGFloat((currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!),
                accuracy: CGFloat((currentLocation?.horizontalAccuracy)!))
            print("loadAd()'s current location is \(LocationManager.sharedInstance.currentLocation)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services not enabled")
    }

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userGender") != nil {
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userGender") == "male" {
            adRequest.gender = .Male
        } else {
            adRequest.gender = .Female
        }
        print("gender is set to \(adRequest.gender)")
    }

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userBirthday") != nil {
        let birthDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userBirthday") as! NSDate
        let now = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
        let components = calendar?.components([.Month, .Day, .Year], fromDate: birthDate)
        let ageComponents = calendar?.components(NSCalendarUnit.Year, fromDate: birthDate, toDate: now, options: [])
        let age: NSInteger = (ageComponents?.year)!

        if age < 13 {
            adRequest.tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
        } else {
            adRequest.tagForChildDirectedTreatment(false)
        }

        print("The user's age is \(age)")

        adRequest.birthday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components!)
    }

    bannerView.loadRequest(adRequest)
}
```

Comment: Instead of storing the recent location in `NSUserDefaults`, see if the `CLLocationManager().location` property will meet your needs. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location)

Comment: Thanks. The issue is it doesn't update quickly enough. I'd like to be able to load geographically tailored ads upon launch. `CLLocationManager().location` is nil when this `viewController` loads due to the short span of time between launch and the initial `viewController` loading. Another second or so and there's a location available, but the `NSUserDefaults` route gets me a value for every situation except the first launch.

Comment: Ohhhhh... Ok. Yep. What kind of accuracy are you talking about? You might be able to pull something comparable from something else. Just as an example off the top of my head, something like timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution which will address every scenario except for the initial launch...

Step 1: Create an `NSUserDefault` in my `LocationManager` singleton class when `currentLocation` gets set:

```
var currentLocation: CLLocation? {
    didSet {
        // Store coordinates as a dictionary in NSUserDefaults
        let savedLatitude: CGFloat = CGFloat((self.currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!)
        let savedLongitude: CGFloat = CGFloat((self.currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!)
        let userLocation: [String: NSNumber] = ["latitude": savedLatitude, "longitude": savedLongitude]
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(userLocation, forKey: "savedLocation")
    }
}
```

Step 2: Tweak `loadAd()` method as follows:

```
    // If location services are enabled...
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        // check if currentLocation has a value
        if LocationManager.sharedInstance.currentLocation != nil {
            currentLocation = LocationManager.sharedInstance.currentLocation
            adRequest.setLocationWithLatitude(CGFloat((currentLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!),
                longitude: CGFloat((currentLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!),
                accuracy: CGFloat((currentLocation?.horizontalAccuracy)!))
            print("loadAd()'s current location is \(LocationManager.sharedInstance.currentLocation)")
        } else {
            // if there's no value stored, tough luck
            if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedLocation") == nil {
                print("No location stored")
            } else {
                // if there IS a stored value, use it...
                print("Using stored location from NSUserDefaults")
                let userLocation = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedLocation")
                adRequest.setLocationWithLatitude(CGFloat(userLocation!.objectForKey("latitude")! as! NSNumber),
                    longitude: CGFloat(userLocation!.objectForKey("longitude")! as! NSNumber),
                    accuracy: CGFloat(3000))
                print("User location is \(userLocation)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services not enabled")
    }
```

[Me upon figuring it out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N0OHdRFcJA)